# How to priotirize package execution in TestNG.xml?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, testng

I am trying to priotirize packages execution in TestNG.xml , but i am not able to below is my xml file and i want to execute package1 first then package2. 
Both the packages contains multiple test classes.

Sample :

```
<test name="Test" parallel="none" preserve-order="true">
    <packages>
        <package name="test.packages.testpackage1"  />
        <package name="test.packages.testpackage2" />
    </packages>
</test>
```

Comment: Isn't it executing it in order right now? testpackage2 executes before testpackage1?

Comment: @eduPeeth Nope it is executing one form package1 then one from package2. No order is maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just separate the packages one above the other:

```
<test name="Test first package" parallel="none" preserve-order="true">
    <packages>
        <package name="test.packages.testpackage1"  />
    </packages>
</test>
<test name="Test second package" parallel="none" preserve-order="true">
    <packages>
        <package name="test.packages.testpackage2"  />
    </packages>
</test>
```

Comment: This solution worked | Thanks :) . we can not put priority="1" for packages?

Comment: You're welcome. For further info please read the official documentation: 
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html